# Are IAM Database credentials enough for public RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I understand that it is a long upheld tradition to put your database servers in a private subnet and use a bastion host to access them as needed. But thinking specifically about cloud architecture, does that setup really make sense anymore?

What I am struggling to understand is why a publicly-accessible EC2 instance, that connects to my RDS servers, is more secure than a publicly accessible RDS instance that implements IAM Database Authentication? In both cases, I would use Security Groups to limit incoming connections.

I am using PostreSQL, and according to AWS documentation, enabling IAM authentication will enforce IAM credentials ( whereas for MySQL, I think password authentication will still work).

So is a bastion host really more secure than IAM Authentication and why?

Comment: Why do you need to increase your exposure surface?  Is there a need - regardless of the apparent caliber of the security - to expose more than is needed?

Comment: @stdunbar  Bastion hosts add complexity to your infrastructure. And from what I can see, either your EC2 instance is exposed or your RDS instance is exposed, and if either one is hacked, your data is gone. So back to my original question, is bastion host more secure than IAM Database Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The best security has **multiple layers of security**. For example, if an ex-staff member has credentials to the database, can they access it from outside of your corporate network? Or if somebody gains access to your bastion, can they also obtain access to the database?

So, yes, it could be considered safe enough to use authentication and to limit access to a specific IP address. It all depends upon your [Risk Appetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_appetite). If the database contains confidential information that would be highly embarrassing for your company if exposed, then the additional layers of security can be worthwhile.

Comment: An ex-staff member would have an IAM user account. When they leave, their IAM user would be disabled/deleted. So using IAM Authentication, they would lose access to the database without us worrying about changing DB credentials. Again, I fail to see how a bastion host is more secure.. what am I missing here???